# is it a way to run javascript function in php file and send the output to client side?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a javascript function in a php file on my server,I want to send data via AJAX, and after that, server(php file) gets the data as a javascript function input,thus runs the function,after obtaining result sends it to client side.in the other words I want to run javascript function in server side(by using php and ajax) not in client side. is it any way to do that?
(for more information web server is Apache)

Comment: Maybe there is a way for PHP to talk to an existing Server-side JavaScript implementation like node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of php's built in functions such as file_get_contents(), file(), etc.

actually it has more features than javascript.
check out the following example of tweeting:

```
  function tweet($message, $username, $password) 
  { 
    $context = stream_context_create(array( 
      'http' => array( 
        'method'  => 'POST', 
        'header'  => sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode($username.':'.$password)). 
                     "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 
        'content' => http_build_query(array('status' => $message)), 
        'timeout' => 5, 
      ), 
    )); 
    $ret = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml', false, $context); 

    return $ret;
  }
```

Comment: The question is about executing arbitrary JS from within PHP, not exactly AJAX or Twitter. I would say - for a few lines of JS code - porting the JS code to PHP is the fastest way. Anything beyond that would be a task for something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).